# Как в QtCreator задать ключи для компиляции

Tags: c++, opengl, компиляция, qtcreator

Из терминала все компилится командой

```
g++ main.cpp -o openglApp  -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
```

Как эти ключи задать в проектном файле Qt Creator

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp



# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление в проектный файл qmake библиотек делается через переменную `LIBS`:

```
LIBS += -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
```